# .NET Website hosted on Azure Windows VM - IIS Web Server fails to work after Server (VM) restart

Tags: azure, iis, .net-6.0, azure-virtual-machine

**Hosted a .NET 6 basic Web App in IIS Web Server inside the Azure Virtual Machine (Windows 2016 Data Center)**

**Commands**:

```
dotnet new webapp
dotnet run
dotnet publish -c Release
```

**3rd command is used for placing release folder files in the Site Physical Path created in IIS Web Server**:

[image]

It shown the result as welcome page. After VM Stop and Start action, it is showing the localhost as "**`The Site can't be reached`**"

If I create new site on Connections of the IIS Manager, then it is working.
Every time after restarting the VM, Creating New Site is not the solution.
Why previously created Site is showing me "**`The Site can't be reached`**" error.

**What I have tried**:

1. Tested by creating new Site in Connections of the IIS Manager, it worked for the new site but after restarting the VM, it also stopped working and showing above mentioned error.
2. Checked VM Status, it is Healthy
3. All required tools are installed in the VM (VS Code, .NET 6 SDK, Runtime, and Hosting Bundle)

**Note:** It is working successfully after I clear the cache in the browser after server restart (stop and start) **but why I have to clear the browser cache every time after VM stop and start**?

**Update:**

***Forgot to mention this:***

I have given HTTPS binding to the IIS Manager Website Hosted so if do localhost with port 80, it will shows IIS Web Served Home Page and localhost with Https (443), it will show the hosted website content.

After Server Stop and Start, localhost with port 80 gives the IIS Web Served Home Page and localhost with Https is not giving the website content, here it is giving error "The site is not reached".

**Fix**:

I have found the fix to this issue which is:

Hosting works with particular time period.
Every time when you launch the Website hosted in VM through IIS Web Server after Server restart (several hours), you need to re-host or create new site in IIS Manager Pool.

Comment: Do you have any other error messages? you can check console or Event Viewer, if not, you can try to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool, this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: No other error message found. IIS Debug Diagnostic tool is new so will check and let you know @samwu

Comment: Delete the default web site and uninstall other applications that might conflict via Windows HTTP API. Then such issues might go away. You set a site binding of `https://*:443` which is quite likely to be blocked by others during VM restart, as another site/app might hook to that binding earlier. You definitely can fix that by creating a new site in IIS Manager, as IIS Manager again overrides the binding for you.

Comment: @LexLi, do i have to create new site in IIS Manager everytime after server restart, this is not the right approach and i do not have any other applications to uninstall except VS Code, IIS Manager and .Net SDK + Runtime+ Hosting Bundle in the VM

Comment: Like I said, if you don't want to recreate a new site every time, you must find the conflicts first and resolve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I got the results like below:***

I have created sample website and when I tried Stop and Start action, localhost reached successfully:

[image]

[image]

As suggested by ***samwu*** you can check event viewer like below:

***In start -> select event viewer -> click Windows Logs node***

[image]

Select application Event Log and Search for errors associated with the failing app like below

[image]

You can make use of [Debug Diagnostics tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-has-stopped-responding-in-iis-995db9a3-a3be-6d20-cf2f-c48101a64444).

Comment: On what, you did the start and stop action?

Comment: Tried in both vm and IIS manage website start and stop.

Comment: Have you seen update in the question

Comment: Yes, I think this issue on your machine you can you diagnostic tool.. as lex Li said u must find conflicts first and resolve them.

Comment: This Week is Holidays time. Will check once b2w.

Comment: Both the Event Viewer & IIS Debug Diagnostic tool helpful & learnt more from this error.